# SWIG(Python): In C, I have Functions with arguements void *, how can i call those from swig

Tags: python, swig, void-pointers

In C, I have function with argument as void* and i am using swig (python) to call those, please let me know how can i call them.

function:

```
extern int test (void* data);
```

Comment: Are you receiving such void* from another C function from your library? And you just need to pass it back to your library?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question...
from python if i am trying to call that function it is saying that 

    "argument 1 expects void *"
and in my case it is not accepting ctypes.c_void_p also